# dual monitors on Ubuntu Jaunty Jackalope 9.04

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors

I finally hooked up two monitors to my Ubuntu box but at a time I can only get one to work.  It always shows one as disabled even though I have it connected.

How do I get both monitors to work at same time?

This is what the settings look like:

[image]

Comment: The image in question seems to be broken - but it is visible at URL http://www.postimage.org/image.php?v=TsIr2r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should enable Twinview (Configure -> Twinview -> Ok). After that you should be able to detect the other screen by clicking `Detect Displays` and set up your config.

Comment: sadly when I click configure only one option is enabled (Separate X Screen).  Other two (Disabled and TwiView) are disabled and I can not select them..

Comment: You have to click on the disabled monitor first. After that you should be able to enable twinview. You can't deactivate your only active monitor ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable it first. Click "Configure", "TwinView", then OK. Set a resolution, drag the screen around, then your monitor will be enabled.